# VueJS 2: Modify select options by other select elements

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have four `select` elements in my template.  The options for each subsequent element are supposed to change based on the preceding selection.  So for instance, if you choose 'Toyota' from the 'Car' `select`, the next  should show only Toyota models.  I tried setting this up, but the AJAX request repeats the call forever.  What's the best pattern for this kind of form?

Here's an example of what I have in the template:

```
<select v-model="selected.car" :change="getModels()">
    <option v-for="car in cars" value="car.id">{{ car.name }}</option>
</select>

<select v-model="selected.model" :change="getYear()">
    <option v-for="model in models" :value="model.id">{{ model.name }}</option>
</select>

...
```

and the javascript:

```
methods: {

   getModels() {
       axios.get('/api/models/'+this.selected.car).then(resp => {
           this.models = resp.data;
   }

  ...    
}
```

So what would be the best pattern here?

Comment: "the AJAX request repeats the call forever." - not sure if relevant to answering the question, but could you explicitly add what this means?

Comment: Yes, when I make a selection on the first select element, the ajax call repeats indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how much data you have, you could load all models directly and then just sort them based on the previous selections. This way, you do not have to deal with Ajax and change-events, you can just have filtered lists based on your model.

You could also use another approach working with indices, given that you have data for every entry you provide. I've built a demonstration for this.

```
Step 1: Create multiple <select>-elements
Step 2: Have lists of manufacturers, models, equipment for every possible index
Step 3: Based on the selected previous index, which you map to a model, iterate over the respective list, also enable the <select>-element
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/NikxDa/pen/EZqJpP

Enjoy.

Comment: This is cool.  But how would you eventually return all the IDs for the selected items?  Right now, I only have keys.

Comment: If it solved your problem, consider giving it an upvote. I don't exactly get what you mean by "return all the IDs" - can you elaborate further?